# How do I get the error reason in Allegro?

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

I come from SDL and there I had a function called [SDL_GetError()](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetError), which returned magically a const char * with the internal error. Here's my piece of code on Allegro 5:

```
#include "game.h"

ALLEGRO_BITMAP *load_bmp(const char *s) {
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bmp = nullptr;
    bmp = al_load_bitmap(s);
    if (!bmp) {

        al_show_native_message_box(display,
            "Fatal Error!",
            "Failed to load: " ,
            s,
            NULL,
            ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);

        al_destroy_display(display);
        return nullptr;

    }

    return bmp;
}

ALLEGRO_BITMAP *player = load_bmp("GFX\\player_up.bmp");
```

The file is ok and I can load directly from al_load_bitmap, but, since I've added my personal function, Allegro crashes and gives me its error dialog (So, bmp must be a nullptr). The problem is that this error for me is absolutely useless, and I need to know what's happening inside Allegro (So, something like al_get_error() would be awesome). How do I know what happened?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the variable player at file scope; in other words, is it initialised before your `main` runs and has a chance to initialise the allegro library?

Assuming this is the case, try changing the line to

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *player = nullptr;
```

and initialise it in a function that you call at the appropriate time during program start-up, like:

```
void init_game_bitmaps()
{
   player = load_bmp("GFX\\player_up.bmp");
   // Other initialisation here ...
}
```

calling it like:

```
// Somewhere in main, or an appropriate function call:
init_game_bitmaps();
```

Comment: It worked! But it makes no sense to me hahaha. Why should I have to define it as a nullptr previously, if I could get the ALLEGRO_BITMAP(s) directly? Well.. Now I'm calling init_game_bitmaps() inside the main function, so I suppose that al_draw_bitmap() inside the main loop was getting the nullptr from game header (Before it was defined in the game.cpp).

Comment: The reason this happens is because allegro first needs to initialize some internal states before certain functions are available to the user, if that internal state is still "invalid" … the functions fail silently (talk about library designs xD)

Comment: @rlam12 You are correct, but I'd like to add that this is a very common design in libraries. The good thing about this is that it allows the library user to decide exactly when to initialise the library.